# How can I get my hero section to look like this?

Tags: text, flexbox, alignment, hero

[Hero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWf48.png)
I'm new to coding and trying to build a portfolio page.
What would be the best way code the hero section to look like this?

Right now my code looks like this, is this the best way to build this section?
Thank you :)

```
<section class="hero-section">
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="oben">
                <div class="text1">DIGITAL</div>
                <div class="text2">PLASTIC</div>
            </div>
            <div class="unten"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```